# dinamcally adding controls C#

Tags: c#, winforms, controls

I'm trying to create a new label on the initialization of the application. I've run trough other questions and answers and made something like this:

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        try
        {
            foreach (Button b in Controls)
            {
                FillBoard(b);
            }
            Label tScore = new Label();               
            tScore.Size = new Size(244, 22);
            tScore.Location = new Point(12, 46);
            tScore.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 9F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
            tScore.Text = "Some text";               
            tScore.Visible = true;
            Controls.Add(tScore);
            Show();
            Refresh();

        }
        catch { }
    }
```

but the label still doesn't appear when i start the app. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you getting any errors? (as in within the `catch`). It seems weird to `Show` from inside the constructor

Comment: An empty catch is evil. It's the programming equivalent of putting black tape over an engine warning light.

Comment: no errors. the app just ignores the existence of the label.

Comment: Might be because you need to add it to `Form1` instance somehow.

Comment: How big is your Form? You're setting location explicitly. Maybe it is outside of Form bounds and that's why you don't see the label.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your application is crashing on `foreach (Button b in Controls)`.
You are trying to cast all Controls to Buttons which is not working.

You should iterate it like this.

```
foreach (Control b in Controls)
            {
                if (b is Button)
                {
                   FillBoard(b); 
                }
            }
```

Comment: well this actually works, only I had to create a new Button c inside of 'if' condition and set it equal to (Button)b, since the fillBoard function only accepts buttons as parameters. But anyway, thank you :)

Comment: @JimmyHabanero - You could always use `foreach(var b in Controls.OfType<Button>())`

Answer (score 0):

Only One Mistake. this.Controls.Add(label);